# How to fix error used by new Place SDK for android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kotlin, google-places-api

I want to get adderss used by new place sdk for android.

refer to https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

I used `com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0`

This is for : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-new-improved-places-sdks

I had used `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0`

I used google sample code. (compat)

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos

I run this project and try to get current place(address).

I could get current place(address) for the first time.

but I could not get this second time.

error code : `9005: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account`

If there is anyone who understands, thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Did you enable google place API on Google Console

Comment: yes, I could get address used by old places sdk and no error code.

Comment: you should enabled the billing account first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you haven't created the billing account for your project.

Without billing account by default **Places SDK** will allow only one load per key per day.

You can follow these steps to resolve the issue :

1-Go to Google Cloud Platform Console.

2-Enable billing account for your project.

3-Select the project that contains the API you want to review.

4-From the list of APIs on the Dashboard, click the name of the API.

5-Near the top of the page, click Quotas or Usage and set the limit according to your usage.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have created my account and used key before google charge system changed.  this means that I haven't created the billding account?

Comment: exactly , you should enable a billing account